# How can I print unsigned integer in decimal number in MIPS?

Tags: printing, mips, unsigned-integer

For example, I want to print this number A0090000(16) in unsigned decimal number in MIPS.
So the print result should be 2684944384(10).
But I got stuck because I only know the assembly code to print signed numbers.

The code is like this:

```
li    $v0, 1    #System call code for print_int
li    $a0, 5    #integer to print
syscall
```

So if I put the A0090000(16) value instead of '5' in that code,
it will print a minus decimal value(since MSB is 1), which is -1610022912(10)
but I want to have the result 2684944383(10), which is read as an unsigned number.

How can I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fill a string with the digits of your number, in reverse order, by successively dividing the value by 10 (unsigned) and adding the remainder's digit onto the start of your string; then print the string.

Answer (score 3):

[The vector value is 36 for printing an unsigned decimal integer.](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html)