# How to store an unsigned 32-bit dword in MIPS

Tags: mips

The allowed range of the values for any register in MIPS are from : -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

However, I don't need the signed integer, so I want the values to be from 0 to 4,294,967,295.

I tried to define dword in MIPS but it didn't recognize the keyword.

Are there any ways to make the register unsigned?

Code I tried:

```
.data


.text


main:
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    
    move $t0, $v0
    
    li $v0, 1
    addu  $a0, $t0, 0
    syscall
```

I tried the instruction

```
addu
```

which is the unsigned addition, but I still cannot store values greater than 2,147,483,647, and the **mars simulator** gives me an execution error

Please don't suggest a string solution. I simply want to store values larger than 2,147,483,647

I have mentioned the signed because the sign **takes** one bit of the register.

Comment: Registers (and memory cells) only store bits.  Whether those bits represent a signed or unsigned integer are up to you.  What code did you try?

Comment: did you mean 32 bit or dword?  A word in mips is 32 bits so a dword is 64

Comment: the instruction determines for that clock period what those bits mean, for example you may have an address, a pointer to an array in there, but when you want to move the address to another item in the array (ptr++), you do an add operation and the bits are now an add operand and not an address as far as that instruction and clock cycle.  they are only an address for the moment it is sampled to generate an address for a load or store or branch.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have updated the post with the code I tried

Comment: @old_timer I need 32bit usigned so I can store values from 0 to 4,294,967,295

Comment: yep, mips registers hold a 32 bit word.  not a problem

Comment: @old_timer yeah, but I need to store larger values above  2,147,483,647, any idea how?

Comment: li should do it just fine if it is not then the problem is the tool you are using and you should pursue that, or is that what you are doing?  saying the tool is broken?  what tool is this?

Comment: your example code shows now attempt to load large values with bit 31 a one or a zero?

Comment: This question made very little sense to me, but maybe this is it: you're doing a "read integer" syscall, and you tried to put a value larger than 2,147,483,647 in there? That's a problem. But it has nothing to do with whether is a register is signed or unsigned (which doesn't make sense)

Comment: so this has nothing to do with mips registers it is about the syscall?  syscalls are specific to the operating system/envoronment/sim, what "system" is this?

Comment: addu is not unsigned addition, that makes no sense.  many have this documented wrong, it has to do with overflow.  add and subtract by definition are not signed or unsigned in the logic, the concept of signed or unsigned addition or subtraction is in the eyes of the programmer, that is what twos complement is all about the alu logic is the same for unsigned and signed.  multiply and divide only if you are mixing sizes of operands and results (obviously if you think about it, you are either zero extending or sign extending).

Comment: Right.  Your code is doing exactly what you want, but the routine you are using to PRINT the value assumes it is getting signed values.  Remember that -1,000,000,000 and +3,294,967,295 have EXACTLY the same hex value.  The difference only comes when you PRESENT the value.

Comment: there is a print string syscall, you can use that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I print unsigned integer in decimal number in MIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435777/how-can-i-print-unsigned-integer-in-decimal-number-in-mips)

Comment: that took about 45 seconds to a minute to find a  number of solutions to this.

Comment: @old_timer that's not a solution, i cannot convert the input integer to a string and do operations on that, like how am I going to add 2,147,483,647 and 2,433,321 if it's a string?

Comment: you  can input a string too.  this sounds like a homework assignment and they intentionally want you to not use those syscalls perhaps?   the syscall definition is the sycall definition (has nothing to do with the mips registers themselves)  if the syscall defintion for those calls is for signed integers then obviously you cannot use those syscalls, end of story.

Comment: @harold I have mentioned the signed because the sign **takes** one bit of the 32bit. and hence it shrink its values

Comment: we are all VERY well versed in twos complement.

Comment: @old_timer it's not like my question requires an Einstein level genius. It's quite simple, is there a solution to this or not. I don't want strings, just direct operations with integers

Comment: you have clearly answered your question though yes?  as have other folks who have asked the same question already.  as have the few of us that have commented here.  What more do you need?  Not going to do the homework for you.

Comment: @old_timer addu does not work, what solution you mean?

Comment: Well it's not like that bit is *gone*, it just has different interpretations depending on the situation. ie whether 0xFFFFFFFF means -1 or 4294967295 comes down to what you do with it. For the purpose of just storing the value there is no issue here, and `addu` cannot possibly be the problem (it's whole thing is that it never raises an exception .. the "unsigned" part is a bit of a misnomer).

Comment: addu is not an unsigned add, there is no such thing as an unsigned vs signed add. yes many folks incorrectly document what the u part means, its not at about the math

Comment: so again system calls are specific to the system not mips mips is not a system.  is this spim is this mars what is this?   depending on the system there may be a syscall, but other wise you simply have to make it a string as the only way to do it.  as answered in other questions and hits on a web search.

Comment: it does take an einstein because there is a long list of problems in your question that dont make sense.  double being 32 bits, mips registers having a notion of signed or unsigned.  mips having a syscall list. the problem apparently having nothing to do with mips registers  If this were not already an answered quesiton it needs a complete re-write.

Comment: BTW `addu $a0, $t0, 0` has a syntax error (not an execution error) since it has 0 in the place where a register must go, `addiu $a0, $t0, 0` would just copy a value from one register to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A register just contains bits -- the interpretation of those bits is up to you.  The value is not inherently signed or unsigned (or even an integer), but generally code will treat it as being some type.

In particular the MARS syscall `1` prints a signed integer.  You probably just want the MARS syscall `36` to print an unsigned integer.

```
li $v0, 36
li $a0, -1
syscall
```

will print `4294967295`

Unfortunately if you're using the old SPIM simulator, it only supports syscalls up to 17, so to print an unsigned, you'll need to write your own code to convert it to a string and print that with syscall 4

Comment: does MIPS have data type "dword" ? my professor asked us to store the values in a dword datatype. I looked for it but couldn't find any

Comment: 'dword' means 32 bits on Windows, but not anything in particular on MIPS